# puppeteer PDF setStyleTag with path option, unexpected token for valid CSS stylesheet

Tags: css, pdf, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

Using handlebars, I have an index.hbs and an alert.css file. I'm attempting to inject the alert.css file as follows:

```
  await page.setContent(await compile('alert', deeta));
  await page.addStyleTag({path: './templates/alert.css'})
  const pdf = await page.pdf({
     format: 'A4',
     printBackground: true
  });
```

The css is valid as I'm able to convert the .hbs file into an html file, using a `link` element. CSS is as follows:

```
body {
  width: 97.7%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Finally the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>My Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1 class="title">RAPID Alert</h1>
    <img src="./logo.jpg" alt="logo here"/>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <img class="dependent-img" src="{{dependentImage}}" />
    <div class="dependent-data">
      <div class="dependent-name">
        <h1>Name: </h1>
        <h1 class="name">Jon Doe Smith</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

When attempting to upload this to a GCP Cloud Function I receive the following:

```
Detailed stack trace: /workspace/templates/alert.css:1
body {
     ^
Unexpected token '{'
```